# Display error message using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a insert stored procedure and I want to check whether the email already exists or not if exists I have to show an error to the user but how to throw the error and catch it in the code behind?

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_ProfileRegMaster]
    @UserId Varchar(50),
    @FirstName Varchar(50)
    @EmailID varchar (50)
    @result int out)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT EmailId FROM Profile_Master WHERE EmailId = @EmailId)
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 0
    ELSE
       RAISERROR ('Email address does not exist.', 1, 1)
END
```

C# code:

```
result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: you need to use SQL Client and do the code via C# code behind.. you need to look at examples on how to connect to SQL Server in C# and how to execute the query in C# Code passing params..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'd not use RAISERROR() in your case. You could do something like this:

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_ProfileRegMaster]
  @UserId  Varchar(50),
  @FirstName  Varchar(50)
  @EmailID varchar (50))
AS BEGIN
  if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
  begin
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  end
end
```

**C# code**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString())
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_ProfileRegMaster", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Pass parameters to Stored Proc...

// Add one more parameter to store the Return Value
var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// Retrieve the return value
var result = returnParameter.Value;
```

Comment: This is what i have done but i want to know about when and where can i use or implement RAISERROR more efficienlty?

Answer (score 2):

[`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) will only throw an exception in the application when the `severity` parameter is >= 11.

Your code is setting `severity` to 1, which is classed as an informational message, and is not returned to the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to throw a custom error from SQL use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), i.e.

```
ELSE
     RAISERROR ('Email address does not exist.', 1, 1)
```

However from your example SQL you could just set `@Result` to something different than your success value:

```
ELSE
    SET @Result = 1 --indicates an error
```

and check the value of `@Result` from you C#.

Comment: so how to catch this @result in code behind?like below

int result;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", result);

Comment: I have amended the example above but I recommend you read the MSDN doc I linked above.

Comment: You don't add the error message to RAISEERROR(), you simply return a value. Then your C# code will translate the value into a message and show it to the User.

Comment: I have amended the question once check it,but i am unable to throw the error.

Comment: @Diego how to catch the result value and show an error message in code behind?

Comment: @Chandrasekhar RAISEERROR() is normally used to report an unexpected condition. In your case, you'd be better off returning a different Result from the Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Diego can you give some example where can i use RAISERROR more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

If your results are only going to be 0 and 1 then @Result should be a bit and 1 means the email address is present and 0 if not then you can check in the code behind if the result is true or false.

EDIT:

To use theRAISEERROR use the following

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
{ ,severity ,state }
[ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
[ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

For Example:

```
 RAISERROR ('Message',10,1)
```

10 is severity and 1 is the state